# Hyperref options

Tags: hyperref, package-options

Consider the following two MEWs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Click \href{http://www.latex-project.org/}{here} to go to the webpage.
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Click \href{http://www.latex-project.org/}{here} to go to the webpage.
\end{document}
```

**Question**

Are the two MEWs equivalent, i.e., are the any difference between `[colorlinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0}]` and `[hidelinks]` as options to `hyperref`? If there are differences, what are they?

Comment: Note the option `hidelinks` is relatively new. I guess, in reaction to user requests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relevant definition of `hidelinks` is

```
 \DeclareVoidOption{hidelinks}{%
 \Hy@colorlinksfalse
 \Hy@ocgcolorlinksfalse
 \Hy@frenchlinksfalse
 \def\Hy@colorlink##1{\begingroup}%
 \def\Hy@endcolorlink{\endgroup}%
 \def\@pdfborder{0 0 0}%
 \let\@pdfborderstyle\ltx@empty
 }
```

which tells us that `hidelinks` is equivalent to the combination of `colorlinks=false` and `pdfborder={0 0 0}`. Setting also the border style to `\ltx@empty` is somewhat superfluous here, as there will be no border.